# How do I get the reverse of the inline formset in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

See this example below in [the documentation of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets):

> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class Author(models.Model):
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>
> class Book(models.Model):
>     author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
> ```
>
> If you want to create a formset that allows you to edit books
>   belonging to a particular author, you could do this:
>
> ```
> >>> from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
> >>> BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book)
> >>> author = Author.objects.get(name=u'Mike Royko')
> >>> formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
> ```

This is a one-to-many relationship with Authors to Books and provides an easy way to edit the books for a single author.

Now I want to do the opposite: a form to edit/create authors with an inline formset of books to edit/create. How do I do that? I would really prefer a way to do this with ModelForms and *without* the need to create an instance of one of the Models involved.

For example:

#### Add Author Form

- Author name: `[________]`
- Books:

  - Title: `[________]`
  - Title: `[________]`
  - Title: `[________]`
  - (add more)
- `[save]`

Note: I need this without any instances of Authors at this point.

I'm probably missing out on something simple here and I've spent a bit too much time on the documentation here. A bit of help is welcome!

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know the answer exactly, but would it be simply okay if I showed you how to reverse it? Not the inline part, just the form in general.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I really need this form to be processed in one go, so I guess that makes having the Book fields inline mandatory. I'm not sure how useful is showing just the reverse, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this using a `ModelForm` for `Author` and a `ModelFormset` for `Book` in the same view.  Something like this:

```
# in forms.py:
AuthorForm = modelform_factory(Author)
BooksFormset = modelformset_factory(Book, extra=3, fields=('title',))

# in views.py:
if request.method == POST:
    author_form = AuthorForm(request.POST)
    books_formset = BooksFormset(request.POST)
    if author_form.is_valid() and books_formset.is_valid():
        author = author_form.save()
        new_books = books_formset.save(commit=False)
        for new_book in new_books:
            new_book.author = author
            new_book.save()
        # not actually needed with these models, but a good habit to include nonetheless
        books_formset.save_m2m()
        return redirect('some-success-view')
else:
    author_form = AuthorForm()
    books_formset = BooksFormset(queryset=Book.objects.none()) # or give a different initial queryset if you want some preselected choice
extra_context = {'author_form': author_form, 'books_formset': books_formset}
return render(request, 'some_template', extra_context)
```

Inline formsets basically do the binding between the author instance and the books instance for you.  Internally, the inline formset uses a queryset based on the instance of the parent model you give it - I think passing in `instance=None` in the `get` code path and if the author form doesn't validate in the `post` would work, but I've never tested that.

Also, I'm not tackling the 'add more' behavior here - the admin gets that behavior from a Jquery plugin, and that should be easy to copy onto your own form.

Comment: Sounds like a plausible solution. I've come halfway into this myself in the meantime - good to see you point me into the same direction! Let me test this in my app now. (and yes, the *add more* button is another issue of course!) Thanks!

Comment: I'm not getting this to work unfortunately, but I think I'm almost there. My `books_formset` appears to be empty at all times (i.e. code in `for new_book in new_books:` is never called). I've made sure the management form is present and correct. Anything missing here still?

Comment: Yes. Had to rework it to be like `for bookform in books_formset.forms: if bookform.is_valid()` (etcetera). That *does* work. So I guess your answer is a bit mistaken here. Now I have issues with File uploads, but that's worth another question.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary - formsets have an `is_valid` method that validates their component forms.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formset-validation

Comment: Ahh sorry, copied the wrong line. I mean, I needed the `for bookform in books_formset.forms:` line to process al forms in the formset. `books_formset.save()` does not provide the list of `new_books` for me. And thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Again, the formset's `save` method is supposed to do this assuming the management form is correct.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset  I've had some problems in the past when working with javascript to add new forms - I'd pay close attention to the POST parameter giving the number of forms in the formset.